# Ordenar registros sem desordenar outros

Tags: sql, sql-server, classificação

Considere a seguinte tabela:

| Id | Grupo | Descrição | Data | Ordem | Tipo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | TesteA | 01/01/2022 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | TesteB | 02/01/2022 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | TesteC | 06/01/2022 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | TesteD | 05/01/2022 | 0 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | TesteE | 04/01/2022 | 0 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 | TesteAA | 05/01/2022 | 0 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 | TesteBB | 02/01/2022 | 2 | 2 |
| 8 | 2 | TesteCC | 06/01/2022 | 3 | 2 |
| 9 | 2 | TesteDD | 05/01/2022 | 0 | 2 |
| 10 | 3 | TesteAAA | 05/01/2022 | 0 | 2 |

**Considerações:**

1. Com exceção do `Id`, todas as colunas são preenchidas pelo usuário.
2. A coluna `Ordem` não tem relação com a coluna `Data`, e vai de 0 a 5.
3. Não pode existir mais de um registro no mesmo `Grupo` e na mesma `Ordem`.
4. Apenas o `Tipo 1` pode estar na `Ordem 0`.
5. A `Data` possui Horas, Minutos, Segundos e Milésimos, mas omiti no exemplo para simplificar.

**Objetivo:**

Gostaria de criar um `UPDATE` que determinasse a `Ordem` para os registros que possuem `0` como valor e são do `Tipo 2`. Sem impactar os que já possuem um valor maior que 0 ou são do Tipo 1. Apesar da Data não ter necessariamente relação com a Ordem, usarei ela como parâmetro para a ordenação dos registros que preciso atualizar.

O resultado desejado seria esse:

| Id | Grupo | Descrição | Data | Ordem | Tipo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | TesteA | 01/01/2022 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | TesteB | 02/01/2022 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | TesteC | 06/01/2022 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | TesteD | 05/01/2022 | 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | TesteE | 04/01/2022 | 3 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 | TesteAA | 05/01/2022 | 0 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 | TesteBB | 02/01/2022 | 2 | 2 |
| 8 | 2 | TesteCC | 06/01/2022 | 3 | 2 |
| 9 | 2 | TesteDD | 05/01/2022 | 4 | 2 |
| 10 | 3 | TesteAAA | 05/01/2022 | 1 | 2 |

**Tentativas:**

Tentei usar o [ROW_NUMBER()](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) da seguinte forma:

```
;WITH ItemsOrdered AS
(
  SELECT *
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY i.Grupo ORDER BY i.Ordem DESC, i.Data) AS row_number
  FROM Items i
  WHERE i.Tipo = 2
)

UPDATE i
SET i.Ordem = io.row_number
FROM Items i
INNER JOIN ItemsOrdered io ON io.Id = i.Id
```

O problema é que dessa forma os registros que já possuem a Ordem correta, não estão sendo considerados na hora de determinar o número da linha.

Existe alguma forma de se chegar ao resultado desejado com um script semelhante ao que estou tentando?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solução foi a seguinte:

1. Precisei determinar a maior ordem de cada grupo através de um `GROUP BY` e o `MAX` em uma subquery. Chamei a nova coluna de `UltimaOrdem`.
2. Foi apenas somar o valor da coluna UltimaOrdem na hora de gerar o `ROW NUMBER`. Note que precisei modificar o `WHERE` para considerar apenas os da Ordem 0 na contagem.

Exemplo da query:

```
;WITH ItemsOrdered AS
(
  SELECT *
     , sub_i.UltimaOrdem + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY i.Grupo ORDER BY i.Ordem DESC, i.Data) AS row_number
  FROM
  (
    SELECT max_i.Grupo
       , MAX(max_i.Ordem) UltimaOrdem
    FROM Items max_i
    GROUP BY max_i.Grupo
  ) sub_i
  INNER JOIN Items i ON i.Grupo = max_i.Grupo
  WHERE i.Tipo = 2
    AND i.Ordem = 0
)

UPDATE i
SET i.Ordem = io.row_number
FROM Items i
INNER JOIN ItemsOrdered io ON io.Id = i.Id
```